# Move all files in specified folder up one directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that extracted files to a series of sub-folders each with a "header" sub-folder. For example:

```
/share/Videos/Godfather.Part.1
  /share/Videos/Godfather.Part.1/<packagename>
    /share/Videos/Godfather.Part.1/<packagename>/Godfather.avi
/share/Videos/Godfather.Part.2
  /share/Videos/Godfather.Part.2/<packagename>
    /share/Videos/Godfather.Part.2/<packagename>/Godfather2.avi
```

I'd like to take the files in the specified folder `<packagename>` and move them up one directory so that the file structure looks like this:

```
/share/Videos/Godfather.Part.1
  /share/Videos/Godfather.Part.1/Godfather.avi
/share/Videos/Godfather.Part.2
  /share/Videos/Godfather.Part.2/Godfather2.avi
```

How can I accomplish this task in bash command line? Mind you this is an example using 2 folders, I have 100's like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share and enjoy.

```
for i in `find . -name "*avi"`
do
    dest=`dirname $i`
    mv $i $dest/..
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps but I want ONLY files in a specific sub-folder named <packagename>.

Comment: Use `-path "*<packagename>/*.avi"` instead of `-name "*.ave"`.

Comment: Note: this will break if any of the matched files have embedded whitespace.  A more robust solution: `find . -path '*<packagename>/*.avi' -exec sh -c 'dest="${1%/*}"; mv "$1" "${dest%/*}"' _ {} ';'`